# IErrorHandler.HandleError(Exception error) method of WCF is getting unexpected TimoutException

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

My intention is to detect unhandled errors inside a WCF service, log them and shutdown the application.

For this purpose I use WCF's `IErrorHandler`. In the method `HandleError(Exception error)` I am notified that an exception occured. Everything works ok. At the end of the question you will find complete listing. Here is the output:

```
00000: Starting service ...
00041: Client call ThrowUnexpected
00056: Service is throwing [InvalidOperationException]
00063: Client chatched [FaultException]
10070: ErrorHandler got [TimeoutException]
10070: ErrorHandler got [InvalidOperationException]
```

There are two things I am unhappy about:

1. Instead of expected `InvalidOperationException` I first get `TimeoutException` and then the one I have thrown. If I would log and shutdown after the first one I will have wrong information in my log.
2. The callback does not arrive immediately, only after about 10 seconds. These seems to be exactly those timeout seconds which are probably default for net.tcp. It is too late for me because I wont to terminate the process immediately after something unexpected happened.

**Question 1:** Is it a bug or is it normal that I get my exception only on second place? Can I assume that for any WCF configuration I will get this pair of exceptions? Is there any way to get only the exception which was thrown inside the method?

**Question 2:** Is there any way to be called immediately and not after timeout?

**Listing:**

```
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.Start();

            Console.WriteLine("{0:00000}: Starting service ...", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

            var instance = new SomeService(stopwatch);
            var uri = new UriBuilder(Uri.UriSchemeNetTcp, IPAddress.Loopback.ToString(), 8085, "SomeService").Uri;
            using (var host = new ServiceHost(instance))
            {
                host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof (ISomeService), new NetTcpBinding(), uri);
                host.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ErrorHandlerBehavior(new ErrorHandler(stopwatch)));
                host.Open();

                // DO NOT DISPOSE Channel is broken
                var proxy = new SomeServiceProxy(uri);
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0:00000}: Client call ThrowUnexpected", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
                        proxy.ThrowUnexpected();
                    }
                    catch (FaultException ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0:00000}: Client chatched [{1}]", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds,
                            ex.GetType().Name);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface ISomeService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void ThrowUnexpected();
}


[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class SomeService : ISomeService
{
    private readonly Stopwatch _stopwatch;

    public SomeService(Stopwatch stopwatch)
    {
        _stopwatch = stopwatch;
    }

    public void ThrowUnexpected()
    {
        var exception = new InvalidOperationException();
        Console.WriteLine("{0:00000}: Service is throwing [{1}]", _stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds,
            exception.GetType().Name);
        throw exception;
    }
}


public class ErrorHandler : IErrorHandler
{
    private readonly Stopwatch _stopwatch;

    public ErrorHandler(Stopwatch stopwatch)
    {
        _stopwatch = stopwatch;
    }

    public void ProvideFault(Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message fault)
    {
    }

    public bool HandleError(Exception error)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0:00000}: ErrorHandler got [{1}]", _stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds, error.GetType().Name);
        return false;
    }
}

public class SomeServiceProxy : ClientBase<ISomeService>, ISomeService
{
    public SomeServiceProxy(Uri uri)
        : base(new NetTcpBinding(), new EndpointAddress(uri))
    {
    }

    public void ThrowUnexpected()
    {
        Channel.ThrowUnexpected();
    }
}


public class ErrorHandlerBehavior : IServiceBehavior
{
    private readonly IErrorHandler m_Handler;

    public ErrorHandlerBehavior(IErrorHandler errorHandler)
    {
        m_Handler = errorHandler;
    }

    public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
    }

    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase,
        Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints,
        BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
        foreach (var channelDispatcherBase in serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers)
        {
            var dispatcher = (ChannelDispatcher) channelDispatcherBase;
            dispatcher.ErrorHandlers.Add(m_Handler);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have a small misunderstanding how the [IErrorHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ierrorhandler(v=vs.110).aspx) works. I refer to the MSDN. First comes the ProvideFault method

> All ProvideFault implementations are called first, prior to sending a response message. When all ProvideFault implementations have been called and return, and if fault is non-null, it is sent back to the client according to the operation contract. If fault is null after all implementations have been called, the response message is controlled by the ServiceBehaviorAttribute.IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults property value.

then comes the HandleError method

> Because the HandleError method can be called from many different places there are no guarantees made about which thread the method is called on. Do not depend on HandleError method being called on the operation thread.

The TimeoutException you are seeing comes from the closing of the ServiceHost (end of the using-Block). You can control this by setting the CloseTimeout on the ServiceHost.

```
host.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
```

Why does the Timeout happend at all?
This is because, the connection from the proxy to the service is still there and not closed, even when the proxy is in the faulted state. To resolve this you need to call Abort in the catch-block of the FaultedException.

```
 catch (FaultException ex)
 {
   proxy.Abort();
   Console.WriteLine("{0:00000}: Client chatched [{1}]", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds,
                            ex.GetType().Name);
 }
```

This will result in the following output

```
00000: Starting service ...
00005: Client call ThrowUnexpected
00010: Service is throwing [InvalidOperationException]
00014: Client chatched [FaultException]
00026: ErrorHandler got [CommunicationException]
00029: ErrorHandler got [InvalidOperationException]
```